# Kafka connect JDBC sink isse with table name containing a " . "

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to build a kafka connect jdbc sink connector. The issue is, the database table name contains a dot and when the connector is created, the process splits the table name in two leading to unfound database table. I tried multiple things to escape the dot so it can be read as a string in the table name but nothing worked ..

Here is the actual name :

"table.name.format":"Bte3_myname.centrallogging",

here is the error :

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table \"Bte3_myname\".\"centrallogrecord\" is missing.

Here is my config file :

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-connect-central-logging-sink",
    "config": 
    {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "3",
        "topics": "central_logging",

        "connection.url": "...",         
        "connection.user": "...",
        "connection.password": "...",
        "table.name.format":"Bte3_myname.centrallogging",
        "pk.mode": "kafka",

        "auto.create": "false",
        "auto.evolve": "false"
    }
}
```

Would someone have any idea about how to parse that correctly in the config file ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `Bte3_myname` should probably go in your connection URL. Tables cannot contain dots. That format is often `[database].[table]`

Comment: you are right, i realisez bte3_myname is the schema but without it my user can't access the table directly .. is there a way to specify the schema in the connection url ? i found nothing about it for Oracle database. I think that you can specify something like &currentSchema for postgres database

Comment: Have you found any references for the jdbc URI format for your oracle database driver?

Comment: no, not yet. I found this site : http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/JDBC-Specifying-Properties-on-the-Connection-URL.htm, its saying we could do something like that : jdbc://com.nuodb://host[:port]/database_name?[connection properties]     -->  jdbc:com.nuodb://localhost/test?user=cloud&password=user&schema=mytest.   i tried adding that at the end of my url connection "?schema=Bte3_utilitydata" but i got a SID not valid error

Comment: 1) user and password are separate properties in Connect config. Don't put them in plaintext in the url. 2) you're missing a port number 3) i think you want this `jdbc:com.nuodb://localhost/Bte3_myname?schema=centrallogging`

Answer (score 3):

In case when a topic name contains dots due to naming reasons, but the table name is just a part of it like `topic.prefix.MY_TABLE_NAME.topic.suffix`, then the sink connector can be configured with a [RegexRouter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) transformation, which can extract `MY_TABLE_NAME` for sinking operations.

The transformation may look like:

```
"transforms": "changeTopicName",
"transforms.changeTopicName.type": org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.changeTopicName.regex": "topic.prefix.(MY_.*).topic.suffix",
"transforms.changeTopicName.replacement": "$1",
```

then the connector will use `MY_TABLE_NAME` as a table name.

P.S. Indeed, the regex should be defined smarter, but it's up to the case, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If bte3_myname is actually your schema, this may work

"table.name.format": "bte3_myname.${topic}"

(give or take one extra underscore).

I also notice you are using mixed case - so you may need to set "quote.sql.identifiers" accordingly.